# PostgreSQL master server hangs on replication flow

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

First of all, I'm not a data engineer, so I'll try to do my best to give you all needed things to resolve my problem :/

**Context:**
I'm trying to create 2 PostgreSQL servers, 1 master and 1 slave.

> psql (PostgreSQL) 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

*As far as I understand, it's not a good idea to do a synchronous replication when we only have 2 servers. But I have to understand what's going on here...*

**Problem:**
Master server hangs when I try to execute a `CREATE SCHEMA test;`.
But, schema exists on Master, and exists on Slave too. The Master hangs because it waits for the slave commit status...

**Configuration of Master:**
*/etc/postgresql/10/main/conf.d/master.conf*

```
# Connection
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,slave-ip'
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/certs/server.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/private/server.key'
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/certs/server.pem'
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
# WAL
wal_level = replica
synchronous_commit = remote_apply #local works, remote_apply hangs
# Archive
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -av %p postgres@lab-3:/var/lib/postgresql/wal_archive_lab_2/%f'
# Replication master
max_wal_senders = 2
wal_keep_segments = 100
synchronous_standby_names = 'ANY 1 ("lab-3")'
```

*/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf*

```
hostssl replication     replicate       slave-ip/32         scram-sha-256
```

**Configuration of Slave:**
*/etc/postgresql/10/main/conf.d/standby.conf*

```
# Connection
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,master-ip'
ssl = on
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/certs/server.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/private/server.key'
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/ssl/postgresql/certs/server.pem'
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
# WAL
wal_level = replica
# Archive
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -av %p postgres@lab-3:/var/lib/postgresql/wal_archive_lab_3/%f'
# Replication slave
max_wal_senders = 2
wal_keep_segments = 100
hot_standby = on
```

*/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf*

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=master-ip port=5432 user=replicate password=replicate_password sslmode=require application_name="lab-3"'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/postgresql.trigger'
```

I got absolutely NOTHING in log files when it hangs, just the error when I Ctrl+C to abort on the master instance:

> WARNING:  canceling wait for synchronous replication due to user request
>
> DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.

Is there a way to check what append, and why it stays stuck like this ?

**EDIT 1**

The content of `pg_stat_replication` :

Before query

```
  pid  | usesysid |  usename  | application_name | client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | backend_xmin |   state   |  sent_lsn  | write_lsn  | flush_lsn  | replay_lsn | write_lag | flush_lag | replay_lag | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------
 54431 |    16384 | replicate | "lab-3"          | slave-ip     |                 |       47742 | 2019-08-06 07:56:48.105056+02 |              | streaming | 0/110000D0 | 0/110000D0 | 0/110000D0 | 0/110000D0 |           |           |            |             0 | async
```

(1 row)

While it hangs / after

```
  pid  | usesysid |  usename  | application_name | client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | backend_xmin |   state   |  sent_lsn  | write_lsn  | flush_lsn  | replay_lsn |    write_lag    |    flush_lag    |  replay_lag   | sync_priority | sync_state
-------+----------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+------------
 54431 |    16384 | replicate | "lab-3"          | slave-ip     |                 |       47742 | 2019-08-06 07:56:48.105056+02 |              | streaming | 0/11000C10 | 0/11000C10 | 0/11000C10 | 0/11000C10 | 00:00:00.000521 | 00:00:00.004421 | 00:00:00.0045 |             0 | async
```

(1 row)

Thanks !

Comment: Check what is in the pg_replication_stat view (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-REPLICATION-VIEW), before it hangs. In particular that the application name is what is expected regarding quotes.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I edited the question with `pg_stat_replication` content before and after a query like `CREATE SCHEME xxx;` ; quoting seems good, but `sync_state` and `sync_priority` seems strange...

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like your standby is not recognized as synchronous standby. Very likely the names are at fault. Try without the double quotes, and if that doesn't do the trick, try without the minus sign.

Comment: Thanks ! Double quotes are mandatory in `master.conf`, but not in `recovery.conf` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Laurenz Albe said, the problem was the quoting of the synchronous standby name.

Documentation explains that it should be quoted in the `synchronous_standby_names` configuration entry on master server if it contains dash, but it must not be quoted in the `primary_conninfo` value on the slave.